# Why am I getting NoSuchElement Exception?

Tags: java, error-handling, game-development

I'm getting the following errors and having troubles with fixing it. Any help is appreciated! Before anyone jumps saying that my code needs to look "cleaner" please know I'm brand new to this and still learning.

When running my Game.java it's giving me this...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at ItemGenerator.textFileReaderSpecialItems(ItemGenerator.java:71)
    at ItemGenerator.<init>(ItemGenerator.java:22)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:9)
    at Game.main(Game.java:16)
```

This is the code around these lines

ItemGenerator.java

```
58    public void textFileReaderSpecialItems(String x) {
59
60        try {
61
62            Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(new File(x));
63            
64            while(fileSc.hasNext() && fileSc != null) {
65
66                String s1;
67                String s2;
68                String s3;
69
70                s1 = fileSc.nextLine();
71                s2 = fileSc.nextLine();
72                s3 = fileSc.nextLine();
73
74                itemsList.add(new Items(s1, s2, s3));
75            }
76
77            fileSc.close();
78        
79        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
80
81            System.out.println("\nError: " + e + "\nProgram exiting...\n");
82            System.exit(0);
83        
84        }
85
87    }
```

```
3    public Game() {
4       
5        LocationGenerator newLocationGenerator = new LocationGenerator("Locations.txt");
6        MainCharacterGenerator newMainCharacter = new MainCharacterGenerator("MainCharacter.txt");
7        CharacterGenerator newCharacter = new CharacterGenerator("Characters.txt", "Jabberwocky.txt");
8        ItemGenerator newItem = new ItemGenerator("Items.txt", "SpecialItems.txt");
9        newLocationGenerator.startLocation();
10
11    }     
12
13    public static void main(String[] args) {
14
15        Game game = new Game();
16
17    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Learning curve for me!

Labeled all my information

Comment: `fileSc.hasNext()` returning `true` does not mean that there are 3 more lines to read.

Comment: I changed it to fileSc.hasNextLine() and its still throwing the error. I'm sorry

Comment: The point is you don't know how many lines are left. `fileSc.hasNextLine()` only tells you you can read **one** more line, not three.

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve] without line numbers so that we can copy & paste the code to try it?

Comment: This in general is a text adv game. Can I zip the folder and add it? Sorry for giving troubles, appreciate y'all offering to help.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read from file portion of 3 lines, but there are not enough lines left to do so. It also looks like each line represents *portion* of data you want. As you see such approach can lead to errors. To avoid it, consider putting data of single item in single line (instead of multiple lines) and for instance separate them with comma or other special symbol like `|`. Then read that line and split it using that symbol. This is basically how CSV files work.   You can also consider using other textual formats like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The following will ensure your list is filled when the input file is valid:

```
public void textFileReaderSpecialItems(String x) {

    try {

        Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(new File(x));

        int lineCount = 0;
        List<String> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {

            lineBuffer.add(fileSc.nextLine());
            lineCount++;
            if (lineBuffer.size() % 3 == 0) {
                itemsList.add(new Items(lineBuffer.get(0), lineBuffer.get(1), lineBuffer.get(2)));
                lineBuffer.clear();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(itemsList);
        fileSc.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.err.println("\nError: " + e + "\nProgram exiting...\n");
        System.exit(1);

    }

}
```

Note that method names should be verb-based, not noun-based. So, something like `fillSpecialItems`. Also, only return an exit code of zero on success. Use `System.err` for errors. Later, you will use `System.err.printf` maybe. Note the format character for a line separator is `"%n"`. What you used (`"\n"`) is OS-specific. Really, if you're not using logging (which you should in real-world, professional apps) you should always use `e.printStackTrace()` for exceptions - you want the maximum info possible.

Comment: Can I do this with the scanner? I also have an array list made already for special items

Comment: With the scanner - no. The list you refer to is the one added to. Did you run the code?